# CSS to change font family in modern communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, communication-site

I have a requirement to change the font family in SharePoint modern communication site. I have found a following extension: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-application-injectcss which can be used to inject css.

Question is, what css class do i need to use to change the font throughout the site? Can someone please help, thanks in advance.

Someone here has done it successfully: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c6f74483-5d13-476d-8069-9f0d04338b92/can-we-change-the-fontfamily-of-our-sharepoint-online-modern-experience?forum=onlineservicessharepoint

But I am just not sure what css classes need to be overwritten for font family purposes, it would be helpful if someone can share some info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change font family for all the text of the modern site page, we can use the CSS style below to achieve it.

```
body,div,span,a{
 font-family: cursive !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @LZ_MSFT, I am going to test this out and mark it as completed if it works.